# Summation convention, partial derivatives.

Tags: summation, partial-derivative, tensors

I've started intro to tensor calculus and I'm pracicing Einstein's summation convention. My taks is to derive the expression for third-order partial derivatives.
 There is a function $f(u) = F(a(u))$
where $u$ represents independent variables $u^1$ and $u^2$, and $a$ represents functions $a^1 , a^2 , a^3$.
I started from first-order derivatives and this is what I got:
$$ \frac{\partial f }{\partial u^{\alpha}} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial a^i} \cdot \frac{\partial a^i}{\partial u^{\alpha}}$$
Moving on to second-order:
$$ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^{\alpha} u^{\beta}} = \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial a^i \partial a^j} \frac{\partial a^i}{\partial u^{\alpha}} \frac{\partial a^j}{\partial u^{\beta}} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial a^i} \frac{\partial^2 a^i}{\partial u^{\alpha} \partial u^{\beta}}$$
Now the fun part, using product rule:
$$ \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial u^{\alpha} \partial u^{\beta} \partial u^{\gamma} } = \frac{\partial a^i }{\partial u^{\alpha}} \frac{\partial a^j }{\partial u^{\beta}} \frac{\partial  }{\partial u^{\gamma}} \left( \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial a^i \partial a^j} \right) + \frac{\partial^2 F }{\partial a^{i} \partial a^j} \frac{\partial^2 a^i }{\partial u^{\alpha} \partial u^{\gamma}} \frac{\partial a^j }{\partial u^{\beta}} + \frac{\partial^2 F }{\partial a^{i} \partial a^j} \frac{\partial^2 a^j }{\partial u^{\beta} \partial u^{\gamma}} \frac{\partial a^i }{\partial u^{\alpha}} + \frac{\partial^2 a^i}{\partial u^{\alpha} \partial u^{\beta}} \frac{\partial}{\partial u^{\gamma}} \left( \frac{\partial F }{\partial a^i} \right) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial a^i} \frac{\partial^3 a^i}{\partial u^{\alpha} \partial u^{\beta} \partial u^{\gamma}}$$
and now the chain rule:
$$ \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial u^{\alpha} \partial u^{\beta} \partial u^{\gamma} } = \frac{\partial a^i }{\partial u^{\alpha}} \frac{\partial a^j }{\partial u^{\beta}} \frac{\partial^3 F  }{\partial a^ \partial a^j \partial a^k}  \frac{\partial a^k}{\partial u^{\gamma}}  + \frac{\partial^2 F }{\partial a^{i} \partial a^j} \frac{\partial^2 a^i }{\partial u^{\alpha} \partial u^{\gamma}} \frac{\partial a^j }{\partial u^{\beta}} + \frac{\partial^2 F }{\partial a^{i} \partial a^j} \frac{\partial^2 a^j }{\partial u^{\beta} \partial u^{\gamma}} \frac{\partial a^i }{\partial u^{\alpha}} + \frac{\partial^2 a^i}{\partial u^{\alpha} \partial u^{\beta}}   \frac{\partial^2 F }{\partial a^i \partial a^k} \frac{\partial a^k}{\partial u^{\gamma}} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial a^i} \frac{\partial^3 a^i}{\partial u^{\alpha} \partial u^{\beta} \partial u^{\gamma}}$$
Well, to me this seems correct, but I would appreciate someone checking or commenting on that.

Comment: So your asking how to use chain rule with Einstein notation?

Comment: @marshalcraft Well pretty much yes, it comes down to that. I've already tried and got some result, now I'm asking if that's correct.

Comment: One way to make this easier on the eyes is to write your partial derivatives in one-line form e.g. $\frac{\partial}{\partial u^\alpha}=\partial_\alpha$. The seeming loss of info re: whether you're considering components of $a$ or $u$ is ameliorated by the use of Latin indices for the former and Greek for the latter. This condenses the first derivative formula to $\partial_\alpha f=(\partial_\alpha a^i) \partial_i F$. (One also sees the comma notation $\partial_\alpha f=f_{,\alpha}$ but this is a bridge too far for me.)